# PHP - Any shorter way for checking all values within three dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, game-development

Basically I have this code scenario:

```
if($_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][0]['currentHealth'] <=0 && 
   $_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][1]['currentHealth'] <=0 && 
   $_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][2]['currentHealth'] <=0 && 
   $_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][3]['currentHealth'] <=0 && 
   $_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][4]['currentHealth'] <=0) {
    //some code here
}
```

Is there any way to check or to loop through all of the indexes if all of 
`['player_1_pawn'][index]['currentHealth']` is smaller than `0`, 
instead of writing it one by one like I posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write a foreach construct that loops through all of the array elements you need to check:

```
$flag = true; // after the foreach, flag will be true if all pawns have <= 0 health
foreach ($_SESSION['player_1_pawn'] as $value)
{
  // for each pawn, check the current health
  if ($value['currentHealth'] > 0)
  {
    $flag = false; // one pawn has a positive current health
    break; // no need to check the rest, according to your code sample!
  }
}

if ($flag === true) // all pawns have 0 or negative health - run code!
{
  // some code here
}
```

Comment: thanks you for the reply, I almost confused because your first solution didn't worked out. This one works fine, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution is to use [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to check the condition:

```
if (array_reduce($_SESSION['player_1_pawn'], function (&$flag, $player) {
    $flag &= ($player['currentHealth'] <=0);
    return $flag;
}, true));
```

P.S. Be careful when array $_SESSION['player_1_pawn'] is empty.

Comment: Ooh yeah, missed about using JQuery, yeah this should work too, thanks